# Saving data to Postgres from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, typescript, aws-lambda

I'm building a lambda function that is supposed to save a game feedback, like a performance grade, into my Postgres database, which is in AWS RDS.

I'm using NodeJS typescript and the function is kinda working, but in a strange way.

I made an API Gateway so I can POST data to the URL to the lambda process it and save it, the thing is, when I POST the data the function seems to process it until it reaches a max limit of connected clients, and than it seems to lose the other clients'data.

Another problem is that every time I POST data I get a response saying that there was a Internal Server Error and with a 'X-Cache→Error from cloudfront' header. For a GET request I figured it out that it was giving me this response because the format of the response was incorrect, but in this case I fixed the response format and still get this problem...

Sometimes I get a timeout response.

My function's code:

```
import { APIGatewayEvent, Callback, Context, Handler } from "aws-lambda";
import { QueryConfig, Client, Pool, PoolConfig } from "pg";

export const insert: Handler = async (
  event: APIGatewayEvent,
  context: Context,
  cb: Callback
) => {
  // context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  const config: PoolConfig = {
    user: process.env.PG_USER,
    host: process.env.PG_HOST,
    database: process.env.PG_DB,
    password: process.env.PG_PASS,
    port: parseInt(process.env.PG_PORT),
    idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
    max: 10000
  };

  const pool = new Pool(config);

  let postdata = event.body || event;

  console.log("POST DATA:", postdata);

  if (typeof postdata == "string") {
    postdata = JSON.parse(postdata);
  }

  let query: QueryConfig = <QueryConfig>{
    name: "get_all_questions",
    text:
      "INSERT INTO gamefeedback (gameid, userid, presenterstars, gamestars) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4);",
    values: [
      parseInt(postdata["game_id"]),
      postdata["user_id"],
      parseInt(postdata["presenter_stars"]),
      parseInt(postdata["game_stars"])
    ]
  };
  console.log("Before Connect");

  let con = await pool.connect();

  let res = await con.query(query);

  console.log("res.rowCount:", res.rowCount);

  if (res.rowCount != 1) {
    cb(new Error("Error saving the feedback."), {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: "Error saving data!"
      })
    });
  }

  cb(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: "Saved successfully!"
    })
  });
  console.log("The End");
};
```

Than the log from CloudWatch error with max number of clients connected looks like this:

```
2018-08-03T15:56:04.326Z    b6307573-9735-11e8-a541-950f760c0aa5    (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: sorry, too many clients already
at u.parseE (/var/task/webpack:/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:1)
at u.parseMessage (/var/task/webpack:/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:1)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/webpack:/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:1)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:607:20)
```

Can any of you guys help me with this strange problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing you need to put creating a pool above the handler, like so:

```
const config: PoolConfig = {
  user: process.env.PG_USER,
  ...
};

const pool = new Pool(config);

export const insert: Handler = async (
  event: APIGatewayEvent,
  context: Context,
  cb: Callback
) => {

..etc
```

The way you have it you are creating a pool on every invocation. If you create the pool outside the handler it gives Lambda a chance to share the pool between invocations.